# @"%@ in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c

I was following a tut and found a line of code like `@"%@ button pressed."`. I'm pretty sure the relevant part is the %@, but is the first @ an escape sequence or what?

Anyways, searching symbols doesn't go well in any search engine so I thought I'd ask. I think the %@ is like {0} in C#?

Comment: Heh, I thought that was a naughty word or something.

Answer (score 9):

`%@` is a format specifier. Functions such as `NSLog` and methods such as `+stringWithFormat:` will replace `%@` with the description of the provided Objective-C or Core Foundation object argument.

For example:

```
NSString *myName = @"dreamlax";

NSLog (@"My name is: %@", myName);
```

This will log the output `"My name is: dreamlax"`. See [here](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFStrings/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1) for more information format specifiers.

The initial `@` symbol at the beginning of the string tells the compiler to create a static instance of an `NSString` object. Without that initial `@` symbol, the compiler will create a simpler C-style string. Since C-style strings are not Objective-C objects you cannot add them to `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` objects, etc.

Comment: What if I wanted to have more than one format specifier? Do I just use two %@?

Comment: @DMan: yes, but be sure to provide two arguments (in the order that you want them to be).

Answer (score 2):

@"some string" means this is an NSString literal.

> The string as show in @"CupOverflowException", is a constant
>   NSString object. The @ sign is used
>   often in Objective-C to denote
>   extentions to the language. A C string
>   is just like C and C++, "String
>   constant", and is of type char *

Answer (score 1):

I found this page which might help - http://www.yetanotherchris.me/home/2009/6/22/objective-c-by-example-for-a-c-developer.html

It seems that you are on the right track.

Comment: As I'm not registered on this account, I can't up vote on this account, but thanks, this looks very useful!

Answer (score 0):

I'm still fairly new to the language, but it looks like the @ specifies that the variable being passed/created is an NSObject, or a compiler directive.

As mentioned above, if you use it like this:

@"someText"

you're instantiating an NSString object, and setting the text of that object to someText. If you look at a good ol' C-style format specifier such as:

..."This is some text, and this is a float: %f", myFloat);

You're creating some text and telling the compiler to put the floating point string representation of myFloat into the string. %@ is a format specifier, just like %f, %d, %c, %s and any other format specifier you're used to. However, if you use %@ as follows:

... "This is some text, and this is an object:%@", myObject];

What you're doing is (I believe) telling the compiler that myObject is an object, and that you want it to include the output of the description method (ie. [myObject description]) in the string that you're creating.